# fixes more = Missing \begin{document}. \begin{table}[] Undefined control sequence. ... & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}

Tags: errors

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
```

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. 
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Numero de Actividad}}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 1}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 2}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 3}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 4}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 5}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 6}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 7}}                                                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 8}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 9}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 10}}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 11}}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 12}}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 13}}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 14}}                                                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Asignacion de Proyecto}}                                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}1er Parcial}                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Asignacion de proyecto\\  para cada integrante\end{tabular}}}               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigacion previa \\  acerca del tema\end{tabular}}}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigacion previa \\  al marco teórico\end{tabular}}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigacion para \\ materiales de adquisicion\end{tabular}}}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigacion para los \\ \\ juegos de niños\end{tabular}}}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2do\\  Parcial\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigación complementaria: \\ asesorías de psicología.\end{tabular}}}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{2do Cuatrimestre}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Investigacion acerca de justmind protptyper}}                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Investigación de páginas\\ web, blogs,páginas de juego, etc.\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}1er Parcial}}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Estructura de la página web}}                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Asesoría con psicóloga}}                                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Entrega \\ de \\ Avance\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Investigación para complementar}}                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Investigación para página de apoyo}}                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}2do Parcial}                                            \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Asesorias para realizar \\ programas\\ (Juegos Didacticos)\end{tabular}}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                      \\ \hline
                                                                                                                                    &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                                                                                                                &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                                                                                     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Desarrolo del sitio web\\ (paginas)\end{tabular}}}                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}1er Parcial}                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}2do Parcial}                                            \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sitios web (proyecto \\ finalizado)\end{tabular}}}                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{actividades elaboradas}}                                                                               & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Fecha de entrega}}                                                                                     & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Actividades en proceso}}                                                                               & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please fix your example, so that it is a smaller example but a _complete_ document that shows the error. Also show the full error message from teh log file, which will show which command is undefined.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're asking.  Or are you saying that the posted code has many errors about `multicolumn` being undefined, but those errors are fixed if you use the two indicated packages?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! ()i) your table (after completing your code fragment) works fine (ii) however it is far to huge that ccan be placed in one frame, even with font size `\tiny`, (iii) it is fill of clutter of unnecessary `\multicolumn...`  (iv) what is really problem?

Comment: This unfortunately appears to be cut and paste from https://tablesgenerator.com thus there will be no sensible preamble or document wrapper it is just a table to embed

Comment: I guess you used `excel2latex` to generate that table. The problem with that tool that you **always have to rework** the resulting code, for example by deleting the not needed commands `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}`. The tool gives you a starting point, but the result of it is far away from beeing perfect ...

Answer (score 1):

as i mentioned in my comment, your table is to huge that can be fit on one frame. after clean-up all clutter from your table, i was able to fit your table on A4 page in landscape orientation:

[image]

in this my effort i use `tabularx` table environment, `scriptsize` font size and determine all except the first column as `p{12mm}` columns type. i also add missing ampersands and remove superfluous ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright}X| *{14}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{13mm}|}}
\hline
Numero de Actividad                                                                                 & {semana 1}    & {semana 2}    & {semana 3}    & {semana 4}         & {semana 5}    & {semana 6}    & {semana 7}    & {semana 8}       & {semana 9}    & {semana 10}   & {semana 12}   & {semana 13}
& {semana 14}   &   \\  \hline
Asignacion de Proyecto                                                                              &   & \cellcolor{yellow}  &   &   &   &   & \cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
Asignacion de proyecto para cada integrante    &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} &                          & & & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline
Investigacion previa  acerca del tema  &   &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow}    &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline
Investigacion previa al marco teórico  &   &   &   & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & & & \\ \hline
Investigacion para materiales de adquisicion  &   &   &  & & & & & & &                          & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & &    \\ \hline
Investigacion para los juegos de niños &   &   &   & & & & & & &  &                          & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcia \\ \hline
Investigación complementaria: asesorías de psicología. & & & & & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{2do Cuatrimestre}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
Investigacion acerca de justmind protptyper                                                        & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &    &   &   & \cellcolor{red!50} &    &   &  & & & & \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15}
Investigación de páginas web, blogs,páginas de juego, etc.  &   &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &                          &                          & \multirow{-2}{=}{\cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial}                                                     &                          &                          &                          & & & & \\ \hline
Estructura de la página web                                                                        & \cellcolor{yellow}  & \cellcolor{yellow}  & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}                                                                                  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15}
Asesoría con psicóloga &  &   &   & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \multirow{-3}{=}{\cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance}&   &   & & & & &   \\ \hline
Investigación para complementar &   &   &   & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &    &  \\ \hline
Investigación para página de apoyo  &   &   &   & & & & & & &   & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcial \\ \hline
Asesorias para realizar programas (Juegos Didacticos)   & & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{yellow} &
\cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance     &                                  \\ \hline
Desarrolo del sitio web (paginas)                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8}& \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor{red!50}1er Parcial                                                                       & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} &                          & & & & \cellcolor{red!50}2do Parcial                                           \\ \hline
Sitios web (proyecto finalizado) &   &   &   & & & & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance &   &   & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor[HTML]{38FFF8} & \cellcolor{red!50}Entrega de Avance                                      \\ \hline
Actividades elaboradas                                                                              & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{yellow}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
Fecha de entrega                                                                                    & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor{red!50}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
Actividades en proceso                                                                               & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{cyan!30}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

i hope that this will help you to rethinking about your table design.